# the use of the word "to expound"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to ask when  we should use prepositions such as "on", "upon" or "about" with the word expound. In [dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/expound) there  are examples showing both usage but I cannot figure out in which conditions I should prefer one to another. Can we say it is optional?

> She expounded her theory further in the course of her talk.
>
> We listened as she expounded on the government's new policies.

Answer (score 1):

***Expound*** means *to set forth, declare, state in detail (doctrines, ideas, principles; formerly, with wider application); To explain, interpret  (what is difficult or obscure)* (OED). The verb is not used with 'on', 'upon' or 'about'.

For example,

*"Our author proceeds to **expound** his own analysis."*

*"The doctrines **expounded** by St. Augustine."*

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have seen many usage with prepositions. http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/

Comment: But you can also *expound on/upon Plato's Republic*. I've never heard of *expounding about*, though.

Comment: @Mrt - yes, so have I (including your Oxford dictionaries link, noting too that they don't provide an example).  *Historically* (i.e. according to the online OED) it appears that *expound on/upon* was not used.  To take WS2 example, *a classics scholar expounds Plato's Republic*.  The fact that I could easily insert 'on/upon' after 'expounds' doesn't make it right, it just means that nowadays some people feel the word needs prepositional support!

Comment: Me too.  Clearly both versions are possible.  Consider this - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expound+on+this%2C+expound+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpound%20on%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpound%20this%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Dan I see your point now.

Comment: @Dan I would tend to agree with that. The modern prepositional support is absent from the OED, but I do think it is so widespread in everyday use that the point has been reached where it should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what [dictionary.com says:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/expound?s=t)

> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to set forth or state in detail: to expound theories.
> 2. to explain; interpret.
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 3. to make a detailed statement (often followed by on).

*Upon* is equivalent to *on*, and it sounds so nice and pompous, just like *expound*.  You may certainly say "expound upon"!

*About* wouldn't be a good choice.

Comment: ... at the risk of making a good word ridiculous!

Answer (score 1):

The use of "expounded" with prepositions such as on, upon, or about is not historically common. The combination of "expounded" and "unto" was much more common. Here are some examples of the use of "expounded" from the King James Bible:

"And the Spirit of the Lord came upon him, and he went down to Ashkelon, and slew thirty men of them, and took their spoil, and gave change of garments unto them which **expounded** the riddle. And his anger was kindled, and he went up to his father's house." - Judges 14:19

"But without a parable spake he not unto them: and when they were alone, he **expounded** all things to his disciples." - Mark 4:34

"And beginning at Moses and all the prophets, he **expounded** unto them in all the scriptures the things concerning himself." - Luke 24:27

"And he began to speak boldly in the synagogue: whom when Aquila and Priscilla had heard, they took him unto them, and **expounded** unto him the way of God more perfectly." - Acts 18:26

"And when they had appointed him a day, there came many to him into his lodging; to whom he **expounded** and testified the kingdom of God, persuading them concerning Jesus, both out of the law of Moses, and out of the prophets, from morning till evening." - Acts 28:23